# DocuSign Powerform URL Parameters for two Recipients

Tags: url, parameters, docusignapi, powerform

Is it possible to add two recipient's parameters to a powerform link? The below link is only populating the first signers information. I'm trying to bypass the first screen where there user would have to populate their name and email.

```
https://powerforms.docusign.net/449cd481-953e-4c47-8e15-d78439fabe?env=na3&acct=be2fe7e7-85a7-4f4d-b38b-8337c7e0f54c&Investor1_UserName=Nicole+Young&Investor2_UserName=Elijah+Cranford&Investor1_Email=nyoung%40exchangeright.com&Investor2_ Email=nyoung%40exchangeright.com&amp%3bpersonName=Nicole+Young
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd signer's Name and Email does not show on the document until it is their turn to sign. 
A workaround I used in order to make the 2nd signer's name appear for the 1st signer was to make a read-only text field and assign it the 2nd signer's name as well.
Example:
Roles - Signer1, Signer2
Add read-only text field named Signer2Name assigned to Signer1 role (otherwise it won't show for Signer1).
URL parameters - &**Signer2_UserName**=**John%20Doe**&**Signer2Name**=**John%20Doe**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are additional URL parameters you can specify like `_UserName` and `_Email`.
Here is all the information - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-using-powerforms?_ga=2.121457160.1624529648.1602795541-1327937497.1596738261&_gac=1.180628053.1599001603.CjwKCAjw4rf6BRAvEiwAn2Q76rqoyyI5hIjap00cyl0siRyM7EFFwLVTQOaLiJ4pjW_RfguQivb6yhoCItQQAvD_BwE